# как вызвать или сгенерировать событие на кнопке гугла

Tags: javascript

но дело в том что там нет атрибута id или class.вот сама кнопка .

```
<input value="Поиск в Google" aria-label="Поиск в Google" name="btnK" type="submit" jsaction="sf.chk">
```

вопрос можно ли как нибудь что нибудь сделать?

просто хочу чтобы моя программа искала за меня в цикле, если конечно это возможно

Comment: что значит "искала за меня" ?

Comment: выбирать элемент можно не только по классу или id но и по наличию определенного атрибута, либо по значению определенного атрибута

Comment: искать можно просто передавая в урл нужную фразу,
https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=qwertyasd

Comment: @Ivan Karaman спасибо...похоже сам бы не додумался.

Comment: и если вы прикрепите событие на кнопку если в пустой вкладке то страница после первого поиска перегрузится и скрипт перестанет работать...

Comment: @ampawd думаю заполнить базу через гугл.

Comment: @Ivan Karaman т.е если значение текстового поля будет пустым?

Comment: почитайте о обьекте location в js.

Comment: @Ben если не пустым, а если пустым ничего не произойдет...

Comment: @Ivan Karaman спс.пойду location прочту.